# Where should I ask my questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions about [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/).

Should I ask them on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), or [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)?
They both have questions about Unity3D.

Where should I ask what kinds of questions?
For example (just guessing):
Conceptual questions on stackoverflow, and specific questions on game dev?

Edit:
I found [this](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18049/unity3d-on-topic-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: If you have a programming question, post it on SO, if you have a question about developing a game, post it on game dev.  Without knowing what your actual question is, we can't know what sites it may or may not be on topic on.

Comment: OK, thanks. That should be an answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Servy mentioned,

> If you have a programming question, post it on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), if you have a question about developing a game, post it on [game dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

I have some things to add:

> If you want someone to review your code, use [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) stack exchange. If you want to ask about general programming logic or algorithms, use [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Or, if it is about computer software (or hardware, which you aren't in this case), use [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

That's where you should ask it. If you want a site specifically for unity3d, you could propose one on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There's already a Unity3D site on Area51, any you're following it!

Comment: @Bobthezealot Oh, right. I forgot about that. Get more people to follow it!